# Reading a file from the directory

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io, filenotfoundexception

im using the scanner class to read the "maze.txt" which is located in my source folder directory, but im getting an error. and here are error im keep getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: maze.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
at mazetr.ch18ex20.main(ch18ex20.java:144).......:
```

---

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException 
{ 
    Scanner in = new Scanner( new File( "maze.txt" ) ); 
}
```

Comment: *Why* is the file in your `src` directory? That directory won't be present at runtime after deployment. Put the file somewhere where it will be found. In this case, the current directory when you execute the program.

Comment: @Goldbones It wasn't posted as an answer. It was a comment. Don't let these simple distinctions elude you. But as a matter of fact I have also answered it.

Answer (score 0):

If You have maze.txt on mazetr package you have to introduce:

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner( new File( "src\\mazetr\\maze.txt" ) );
```

If you have maze.txt on another package:

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner( new File( "src\\anotherpackage\\maze.txt" ) );
```

Comment: sure thing...ill send it now

Comment: i resend again just now

Comment: this is what i get now